# PHPunit says 2 tests and 2 assertion eventhough i did not write a single test function yet

Tags: phpunit

No tests found in class "Test\GroupControllerTest".

phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:152
phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:104

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.

as you see the output of PHPunit says no test in class but I could not understand why it says in bottom Tests: 2, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.

Can anybody please help me to understand that?

Comment: Were there tests in any other files that were executed?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I had a test file that I forget to remove.